# How to find "Display name" of a service in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-services

I have a service which is running in a system in several instances. I need to find `DISPLAY_NAME` of the service from the service. I've tried `ServiceBase.ServiceName` but it returns (probably) the name of service from the project installer, which is at least in this case useless.

The service is installed by `installutil` with a parameter `/name=`.

**Edit**

I have a workaround based on Imran Balouch answer. I read the name in the installer `Me.Context.Parameters("name")` and write it to `ImagePath` registry subkey and read it with Environment.GetCommandLineArgs in a service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added `ProjectInstaller` in your windows service project? If yes than in ProjectInstaller you add `ServiceInstaller` for your service, and in that ServiceInstaller you can specify the display name of the service. Select that serviceinstaller and in properties set its `Display Name`  or in `InitializeComponent` of `ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs` or `ProjectInstaller.Designer.vb` you can specify the display name as:

```
this.yourServiceInstaller.DisplayName = "Service Display Name";
```

Comment: The service is installed by installutil with specified name.

Comment: But you would have added a projectinstaller in your windows service project, isn't it so?

Comment: Yes, there is a MultiProjectInstaller.vb. So some solution is to read the /name (if possible and set it).

Answer (score 4):

You can get a service's display name, given its short ServiceName, by using the [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(this.ServiceName);
var displayName = sc.DisplayName;
```

As you said, you can get the `ServiceName` easily, as it's a member of your own class, inherited from `ServiceBase`. This service name will be *different* for different instances of the services running on the same machine, since it's a unique identifier.

Comment: It stops with an error "Invalid value  for parameter name." And works when I specify the correct name but it is what I am looking for.